# why variable is nil although I put there reference to object

Tags: go, mgo

I cannot figure out why after calling `ConnectToMongo` variable `session` is still nil. I would understand it if `ConnectToMongo` accepts not reference type like `ConnectToMongo(session mgo.Session)` but reference variable type `*mgo.Session` must be saved after returning function `ConnectToMongo`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

func ConnectToMongo(session *mgo.Session) {
    if session == nil {
        var err error
        session, err = mgo.Dial("localhost:27028")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    var session *mgo.Session
    ConnectToMongo(session)
    if session == nil {
        fmt.Println("nil. Why?")
    }
}
```

It outputs:

`nil. Why?`

## Update

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

func ConnectToMongo(session **mgo.Session) {
    if session == nil {
        var err error
        *session, err = mgo.Dial("localhost:27028")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    var session *mgo.Session
    ConnectToMongo(&session)
    if session == nil {
        fmt.Println("nil. Why?")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("not nil. Ok.")
    }
}
```

The same output:

```
nil. Why?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer to pointer to store the value of the pointer. Otherwise your are copying the value of the pointer to the `ConnectToMongo` function.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

func ConnectToMongo(session **mgo.Session) {
    if *session == nil {
        var err error
        *session, err = mgo.Dial("localhost:27028")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    var session *mgo.Session
    ConnectToMongo(&session)
    if session == nil {
        fmt.Println("nil. Why?")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the same output: `nil. Why?`

Comment: there was an error in the previous code. `if *session == nil` note the `*`. Fixed.